# Specifying A Scope for Sig in Alloy

Tags: java, oop, alloy

i am new to Alloy and there is an error due to which my program can't execute or show.
Error iam having is

> A Syntax error has occurred:
>   You must specify a scope for "this/Name"

My Code is

```
    module language/Family
sig Name { }
abstract sig Person {
  name: one Name,
  siblings: Person,
  father: lone Man,
  mother: lone Woman
  }
sig Man extends Person {
  wife: lone Woman
  } 
sig Woman extends Person {
  husband: lone Man
  }
sig Married extends Person {
  }
fact {
  no p: Person | p in p.^(mother + father)
  wife = ~husband
}
fun grandpas[p: Person] : set Person {
  let parent = mother + father + father.wife + mother.husband | p.parent.parent & Man
  }
pred ownGrandpa[p: Person] {
  p in grandpas[p]
  }
```

These are my run commands

```
run ownGrandpa for 4 Person
run ownGrandpa for 2 Person
run ownGrandpa for 1 Person
```

Can Any one point out This Error for me Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to assign a scope to your model.

The first one is by assigning a scope to each signature of your model.
e.g. : `run ownGrandpa for 4 Person, 3 Name`

The second one is by giving a global scope that will be applied to all the signatures. 
e.g. `run ownGrandpa for 4`

The last one is a mix of the two previous and consists of a global scope accompanied by one or several individual scope definitions.
e.g. `run ownGrandpa for 5 but 4 Person.`
The global scope is to be applied to all the signature for which an individual scope declaration is missing.

Thus, in your example, `run ownGrandpa for 5 but 4 Person` is equivalent to  `run ownGrandpa for 5 Name, 4 Person`

Note that providing scopes like this only gives an upper bound to the number of atoms derived from a signature.

If you want to express that any of your instance should contain exactly 4 persons (no more, no less) then you should use the keyword `exactly`.
e.g.  `run ownGrandpa for 5 but exactly 4 Person`