# Why doesn't simple integer counterexample occur in Alloy?

Tags: scope, alloy, formal-verification, formal-methods

I am trying to model a relationship between a numeric variable and a boolean variable, in which if the numeric variable is in a certain range then the boolean variable will change value.  I'm new to Alloy, and am having trouble understanding how to constrain my scope sufficiently to yield the obvious counterexample.  My code is as follows:

```
open util/boolean 

one sig Object {
    discrete : one Bool,
    integer : one Int
}

fact { all o : Object | o.integer > 0 and o.integer < 10 }
fact { all o : Object | o.integer > 5 iff o.discrete = False }

assert discreteCondition { all o : Object | o.discrete = True }

check discreteCondition for 1000
```

Since `o.integer` is integer-values and ranges from 0 to 10, it could only be one of 10 different choices.  And I specified that each `Object` should only have one `integer` and one `discrete`.  So it seems reasonable to me that there are really only 10 cases to check here: one case for each value of `integer`.  And yet even with 1000 cases, I get

> No counterexample found.

If I remove the `integer` variable and related facts then it does find the counterexample almost immediately.  I have also tried using other solvers and increasing various depth and memory values in the Options, but this did not help, so clearly my code is at fault.

How can I limit my scope to make Alloy find the counterexample (by iterating over possible values of the `integer`)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the bitwidth used to represent integers is 4 so only integer in the range [-8,7] are considered during the instance generation, and so, due to integer overflows, your first fact is void (as 10 is outside this range).

To fix the problem, increase the bitwidth used to at least 5:

```
check discreteCondition for 10 but 5 Int.
```

Note that a scope of 1000 does not mean that you consider 1000 case in your analysis. The scope is the maximum number of atoms present in the generated instance, typed after a given signature. In your case you have only one signature with multiplicity one. So analyzing your model with a scope of 1 or 10000 doesn't change anything. There'll still be only one Object atom in the instance generated. 
You might want to check this Q/A to learn more about scopes [Specifying A Scope for Sig in Alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360214/specifying-a-scope-for-sig-in-alloy)